# sbt define run-task using different configuration

Tags: sbt

Imagine I would like to define a sbt task which is the equivalent of

```
sbt runDev "-Dconfig.resource=dev.conf"
```

and then call it via

```
sbt runDev
```

runDev is custom run-task in that case. How would the part of my build.sbt look like? Ideally I would like to do something like

```
javaOptions in runDev += "config.resource=application-dev.conf"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself

```
fork in runDev := true
javaOptions in runDev ++= Seq("-Dconfig.resource=dev.conf")
```

The fork is important otherwise it wont start a new JVM with the corresponding java options!